# Diference between Storage allocation and memory allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management

I want to know that if there is any difference in storage allocation and memory allocation in c and what exactly is storage allocation??

Comment: In what context have you seen these two terms?

Comment: For me it's the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C the word *storage* is usually used in the context of [**storage class**](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-storage-class) of a variable: `auto`, `static`, `extern`, `register`, which specifies the way memory will be allocated the variable.  Memory allocation can be [static, automatic, and dynamic](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Allocation-and-C.html).

In general sense 'storage' means just memory. So in your context I think they are synonyms
but its better to use 'memory allocation' in order not to confuse with storage class.